# verizon iphone4: if it has access to wifi and 3G which will it use and what's best for battery life

Tags: iphone, wifi, cellular-carriers

At home, my iphone has a strong signal to Verizon's 3G network and my home WiFi network.  In the interest of battery life, which connection will iphone use if it has access to both networks?  Also, given strong connections to both networks, what's the best way to optimize for battery life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhones will always use a wireless connection if one is available (and it is authorised to use it).  It will then use 3G (EV-DO).  And then 1xRTT as a last resort.  So it always prioritises wireless if available.

Wireless is generally better on battery life too.

Comment: Instead of manually disabling/enabling WiFi when I leave/return home, is there any way to do this  automatically?  Some app perhaps?

Comment: @Sajee: No app can control the radios (without jailbreaking)
@RobZolkos: Verizon doesn't have EDGE. Verizon would use 1xRTT if EV-DO isn't available.

Comment: cool thanks.  We don't have verizon here in Australia so wasn't sure what it was called.  Amended answer.